# SQlite DB BRowser - Create users in auth_user table by SQL - how to hash password?

Tags: sql, django, db-browser-sqlite

Maybe I am doing something wrong but I would like to create data for my Django app tests and first, I would like to create users using sql script in DB Browser SQLite

```
   INSERT INTO
   auth_user (date_joined, username, first_name, last_name, email, is_active, is_superuser, is_staff, password) 
VALUES
   (
      DateTime('now'), 'Hamilton', 'Laird', 'Hamilton', 'laird.hamilton@surf.com', 1, 0, 0, 'mereva2019'
   )
;
```

but as password is not encrypted it does not work
is there a way to correctly encrypted password?

what would be the good way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The password isn't stored in plaintext; it has to be encrypted.  I used this code in the Django shell:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = Users.objects.get(username='myuser')
user.set_password('mypassword')
user.save()
```

Comment: thanks but I want to create a SQL script in DB Browser for SQLite

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can use `SQLCipher` which is password management tool

As per its description

`SQLCipher` is an extension to `SQLite` that provides transparent 256-bit AES encryption of database files. Pages are encrypted before being written to disk and are decrypted when read back.

You can find more content on below site.

https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/